# Cart Array trouble, cart.total_price

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, sum, undefined, shopping-cart

I'm programming a cart system for one website in RoR and I have a strange problem with my cart.

I already made another app with the same cart model and didn't have this problem.

So here is the situation:

- add product to my cart, that's ok.
- write cart.total_item, that's ok.
- write cart.total_price, this fail.

My app tell me the '*method*' I'm trying to use to calculate '*cart.total*_ *price*' is '*undefined*'.

Here is the record:

Showing */var/rails/caveSACMS/app/views/catalogues/index.html.erb* where line #196 raised:

```
    undefined method `prod_pxuttc' for #<Array:0x00000005ce09f0>
```

Extracted source (around line #196):

```
    193:       </tr>
    194:       <tr style="background-color:#2c2c2c;">
    195:         <th style="text-align:center;padding:2px;color:#a2a2a2;">
    196:           Total: <%=@cart.total_price%>
    197:         </th>
    198:       </tr>
    199:       <tr style="background-color:#2c2c2c;">
```

Rails.root: /var/rails/myApp

```
    app/models/cart.rb:15:in `block in total_price'
    activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb:60:in `map'
    activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb:60:in `sum'
    app/models/cart.rb:15:in `total_price'
    app/views/catalogues/index.html.erb:196:in `_app_views_catalogues_index_html_erb___2685208389527055012_43230480'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `block in render'
    activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/template.rb:141:in `render'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
    activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
    activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:40:in `block in render_template'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:48:in `render_with_layout'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:39:in `render_template'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:12:in `render'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:109:in `_render_template'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
    activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
    /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:310:in `realtime'
    activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
    activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__1902602080326961788__process_action__2511143183103068215__callbacks'
    activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
    activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
    activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
    activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
    activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:205:in `process_action'
    activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:66:in `dispatch'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:30:in `call'
    journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
    journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
    journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:589:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
    rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
    rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
    rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
    rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
    activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
    activerecord (3.2.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
    activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2985483728309837116__call__1908674296767231568__callbacks'
    activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
    activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
    railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
    railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
    rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
    rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
    activesupport (3.2.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
    rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
    actionpack (3.2.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
    railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
    railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
    rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
    railties (3.2.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
    rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
    /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
    /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
    /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

**Request**

Parameters:

```
    {"region"=>"2",
     "categorie"=>"-1",
     "millesim"=>"-1",
     "price_from"=>"",
     "price_to"=>"-1",
     "cart_action"=>"-1",
     "to_add"=>"-1",
     "show_cart"=>"-1"}
```

**Show session dump**

```
    _csrf_token: "kDD3qIZpvZInGWKclqSUQoyraIkcs20VKbhBMBZezJ4="
    cart: #<Cart:0x00000005ce0a68 @items=[[#<CsaV3Prd prod_wid: 6024, prod_cid: 907509, prod_pxuttc: #<BigDecimal:5ce07e8,'0.36E2',9(18)>>]], @total_price=0>
    session_id: "7efaefcb7af5aa99d68c7466c1e7ee4c"
```

---

In my controller I have my cart '*Initialization*' as needed.

```
    class CataloguesController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @cart = find_cart
        @items = @cart.items
      end
    end
```

Here is my Cart Model:

```
    class Cart
      attr_reader :items

      def initialize
        @items = []
        @total_price = 0
      end

      def add_product(product)
        @items << product
        product
      end

      def total_price
        @items.sum{ |item| item.prod_pxuttc}
      end

      def total_items
        @items.length
      end
    end
```

I don't understand why on this app the action '*total*_ *price*' don't work. My other app work fine with the same model.

The only difference between the two apps is that:

- on the Not-Working app, the column for the item price is '*decimal(10,2)*' type.
- on the Working app, the column for the item price is '*int(11)*' type.

And the most strange thing is that I can sort and render the column '*prod_pxuttc*' from the table into a listing. It renders the value.

Here is the two differents order to sort the same value from the table:

- First method (working and rendering the value): *(this order sorts many items)*

```
    @prod = CsaV3Prd.find(:all,{:conditions=>["prod_cat = ?","#{params[:categorie]}"],:order=>"prod_cid DESC"})
```

- Second method (the cart method that doesn't work and call the error): *(this order sort one unique item)*

```
    product = CsaV3Prd.find(:all,{:select=>["prod_wid, prod_cid, prod_pxuttc"],:conditions=>["prod_cid = ?","#{params[:to_add]}"],:order=>"prod_cid DESC"})
```

If someone know how to solve the problem, or if there is already a thread for this trouble *(I searched and didn't find)* please tell me.

Thanks.

*EDIT 29-05-2012*

**Resolved**

So the problem was about selecting an Array.

By selecting one single item to put into the cart, all works.

I replaced the parameter *':all'* by *':first'*.

Thanks to Frederick Cheung for his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
product = CsaV3Prd.find(:all,{:select=>["prod_wid, prod_cid, prod_pxuttc"],:conditions=>["prod_cid = ?","#{params[:to_add]}"],:order=>"prod_cid DESC"})
```

returns an array (possibly containing one element), not a single product. Use `find :first` if you only want one item.

You can also see this from the dump of the session you provided, where you can see that @items is an array of array (see how it starts with [[ ? )

Not related to your problem, but

```
:select=>["prod_wid, prod_cid, prod_pxuttc"]
```

working is probably an accident (due to what Array#to_s does), what you probably should be doing is

```
:select=>"prod_wid, prod_cid, prod_pxuttc"
```

Comment: I used the same method on my first App (except the :select to take only needed information) and I can use the total_price fonction without trouble.

Comment: It all depends on what you do with that return value - if you treat it like a single product it just won't work, because it isn't - it's an array (also note that even when you fix this, your cart still contains bad data - you'll need to clear it out)

Comment: I want to return the "prod_pxuttc" value from on choosed item. Then I need to render a "total price" value, (price value = prod_pxuttc). But I can't return anything stored in the Cart. I don't understand why I can't, because I already used this cart on another App and on this Other App all is working as well.

Comment: I've tried to explain several times - there is nothing wrong with the cart - it's what you are putting to the cart: arrays rather than individual objects.

Comment: yes it's an array, but this array can have only one object. can you tell me how to do to select ONE object from my table by giving one parametre of selection (like ID).

Comment: Ok so I changed my :all to :first. And it's working. You saved me.

Thanks a LOT!